# Change save text for check-icon like Telegram on DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialogfragment, android-menu

I created a full-screen Dialog using DialogFragment, as shown [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#FullscreenDialog). In my implementation, I created a Menu XML file to be called on the DialogFragment:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_save"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Inserir"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

The problem is that I would like to use a check/confirm icon instead of the default `SAVE` message implied in Material Design, just like the one Telegram uses when trying to edit a group name (see below).

[image: Telegram editing group's name]

Is there a default icon in Android like this one in Telegram? How to change the text for the icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a standard checkmark image asset. To add it to your project, navigate to your `res/drawable` directory in Android Studio and `Right click -> New -> Image Asset`. In the wizard that opens, change "Icon Type" to "Action Bar and Tab Icons", then click on the "Clip Art" button to change the icon. Search for "check" and you'll find it.

[image]

To change the text to this new image, add the `android:icon` attribute to your menu item, using the name you chose in the above wizard.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_save"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Inserir"
    android:icon="@drawable/checkmark"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

Comment: This worked, but the icon is pretty small. How can I resize it to match the `back arrow` size?

Comment: Got it to work. Instead of using the ClipArt icon, I added as a Vector Asset and changed the `android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel` for the `close` Vector Asset icon also.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an icon attribute in xml

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_save"
    android:orderInCategory="100"     
    android:title="Inserir"     
    android:icon="@drawable/your_icon"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

If you want to get this icon, you can right click on resources folder on your project, hit "add vector image" then you can create an xml vector image from the material icons.